# CSS: centered content, left aligned background image

Tags: html, css

i need to implement the following layout:

[image]

the content wrapper has a fixed size and will be centered:

```
.content
{
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

the problem is, how to implement the left-aligned background bar from the sub-navigation (see arrow)?

i dont want to use javascript + onresize or something.
any ideas?

thanks

my markup looks like

a standard page layout

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="header">
        <strong>Header:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tortor. Praesent dictum, libero ut tempus dictum, neque eros elementum mauris, quis mollis arcu velit ac diam. Etiam neque. Quisque nec turpis. Aliquam arcu nulla, dictum et, lacinia a, mollis in, ante. Sed eu felis in elit tempor venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut ultricies porttitor purus. Proin non tellus at ligula fringilla tristique. Fusce vehicula quam. Curabitur vel tortor vitae pede imperdiet ultrices. Sed tortor.
    </header><!-- .header-->
    <main class="content">
        <strong>Content:</strong> Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. Quisque vitae pede. Nam et augue. Sed a elit. Ut vel massa. Suspendisse nibh pede, ultrices vitae, ultrices nec, mollis non, nibh. In sit amet pede quis leo vulputate hendrerit. Cras laoreet leo et justo auctor condimentum. Integer id enim. Suspendisse egestas, dui ac egestas mollis, libero orci hendrerit lacus, et malesuada lorem neque ac libero. Morbi tempor pulvinar pede. Donec vel elit.
    </main><!-- .content -->
<footer class="footer">
    <strong>Footer:</strong> Mus elit Morbi mus enim lacus at quis Nam eget morbi. Et semper urna urna non at cursus dolor vestibulum neque enim. Tellus interdum at laoreet laoreet lacinia lacinia sed Quisque justo quis. Hendrerit scelerisque lorem elit orci tempor tincidunt enim Phasellus dignissim tincidunt. Nunc vel et Sed nisl Vestibulum odio montes Aliquam volutpat pellentesque. Ut pede sagittis et quis nunc gravida porttitor ligula.
</footer><!-- .footer -->
```

```
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.header {
    height: 47px;
    background: #FFE680;
}


/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.content {
    padding: 0 0 100px;
}




/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: -100px auto 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: #BFF08E;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Provide a JS FIDDLE code will be helpful.

Comment: it's a standard layout (just like the snippet from alex wilson below) but should have a (sub-navi) div which starts from the total left border and should auto-resize to the centered wrapper

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want because the picture that you have provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DdCJi)

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="bar">test</div>
  <div class="cnt">Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {margin: 0}
.bar {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-right: calc((100% - 960px)/2)
}
.cnt {
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 600px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

Comment: never seen this before but it's what i wanted :) does it work crossbrowser? thanks

Comment: @Fuxi : i would suggest to look for `css display:table` property, `calc` is still widely unsupported and `display:table/table-cell` provides for better layout handling IE8+!!

Answer (score 0):

a standard page layout

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="header">
        <strong>Header:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tortor. Praesent dictum, libero ut tempus dictum, neque eros elementum mauris, quis mollis arcu velit ac diam. Etiam neque. Quisque nec turpis. Aliquam arcu nulla, dictum et, lacinia a, mollis in, ante. Sed eu felis in elit tempor venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut ultricies porttitor purus. Proin non tellus at ligula fringilla tristique. Fusce vehicula quam. Curabitur vel tortor vitae pede imperdiet ultrices. Sed tortor.
    </header><!-- .header-->
    <main class="content">
        <strong>Content:</strong> Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. Quisque vitae pede. Nam et augue. Sed a elit. Ut vel massa. Suspendisse nibh pede, ultrices vitae, ultrices nec, mollis non, nibh. In sit amet pede quis leo vulputate hendrerit. Cras laoreet leo et justo auctor condimentum. Integer id enim. Suspendisse egestas, dui ac egestas mollis, libero orci hendrerit lacus, et malesuada lorem neque ac libero. Morbi tempor pulvinar pede. Donec vel elit.
    </main><!-- .content -->
<footer class="footer">
    <strong>Footer:</strong> Mus elit Morbi mus enim lacus at quis Nam eget morbi. Et semper urna urna non at cursus dolor vestibulum neque enim. Tellus interdum at laoreet laoreet lacinia lacinia sed Quisque justo quis. Hendrerit scelerisque lorem elit orci tempor tincidunt enim Phasellus dignissim tincidunt. Nunc vel et Sed nisl Vestibulum odio montes Aliquam volutpat pellentesque. Ut pede sagittis et quis nunc gravida porttitor ligula.
</footer><!-- .footer -->
```

```
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.header {
    height: 47px;
    background: #FFE680;
}


/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.content {
    padding: 0 0 100px;
}




/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: -100px auto 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: #BFF08E;
    position: relative;
}
```